# How to fit hierarchical models on big data with repeated observations

Tags: r, bigdata, hierarchical-data, lme4

I am working with online behavioral data where each user has multiple Bernoulli trials. I am familiar with fitting hierarchical models using `lme4` in R, but now that my dataset has ~1MM unique users and 1-10 observations each, the `lme4` model is running endlessly on my Macbook Pro. I had previously only ever fit such models to a few thousand users and run time was manageable.

```
library(lme4)
glmer(outcome ~ treatment + (1|user_id), family = 'binomial', data = mydata)
```

How might I practically approach fitting a hierarchical model to such a large dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to speed up a `glmer`:

- Try setting `nAGQ = 0` within the `glmer` call
- Try specifying `"nloptwrap"` as your optimizer in `glmerControl`
- Try specifying `calc.derivs = F` in `glmerControl`

[More info here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmerperf.html)

```
# code example
glmer(
    outcome ~ condition + (1|user_id),
    family = "binomial", 
    data = mydata, 
    nAGQ = 0,
    control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE)
)
```